# setting date in javascript with getDate

Tags: javascript

The following javascript, processed via webpacker is setting the UI with the proper startDate (assuming today is 2020-12-19: 2018-12-19), but not the endDate, which is shown as `2020-12-19`

```
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([[0],{

/***/ "./app/javascript/src/promotion_datespan.js":
/*!**************************************************!*\
  !*** ./app/javascript/src/promotion_datespan.js ***!
  \**************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function($) {$(function () {
  var startDate = new Date();
  startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() - 2);
  $('#date_from').fdatepicker({
    initialDate: startDate,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    disableDblClickSelection: true,
    leftArrow: '<<',
    rightArrow: '>>',
    closeIcon: 'X',
    closeButton: true
  });
});
$(function () {
  var endDate = new Date();
  endDate.getDate(endDate.getDate() - 2);
  $('#date_to').fdatepicker({
    initialDate: endDate,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    disableDblClickSelection: true,
    leftArrow: '<<',
    rightArrow: '>>',
    closeIcon: 'X',
    closeButton: true
  });
});
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(this, __webpack_require__(/*! jquery/src/jquery */ "./node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js")))

/***/ })

}]);
//# sourceMappingURL=0-0fcba24322adb18c7ad0.chunk.js.map
```

why is `getDate`returning the wrong data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo, use `endDate.setDate` in stead off `endDate.getDate`.

I assume you want the `endDate` to be 2 days earlier then the current date.